# Not enough arguments for format string Python-MySQL

Tags: python, mysql

I'm getting this error in python and i don't know how to solve it. Sorry for my english, is not my native language :(

**TypeError: not enough arguments for format string**

```
save_data = "INSERT INTO mediciones_historial VALUES('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')" % (sensor, data, data_type)
```

In my database I have five rows:

id (int)
sensor (int)
data (text)
data_type(text)
fecha(timestamp)

What is that I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code:

```
save_data = "INSERT INTO mediciones_historial VALUES('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')" % (sensor, data, data_type)
```

The number of %s specifier doesn't matches number of arguments you are passing, also the column names are missing after table name

you have to make it according to the column in table 
but python always have a better choice.

Try using this :

```
save_data = "INSERT INTO mediciones_historial(column1,column2,column3) VALUES({0},{1},{2})".format(sensor, data, data_type)
```

but you have to take care of data type i.e if it is string or date type then use single quotes(') : '{0}' instead of {0}.

Also the above seems more understandable and readable. :)

Comment: I am glad that it helped . You may like to accept my answer also :)

Comment: This is terrible. This is vulnerable to SQL injection.

execute("INSERT INTO mediciones_historial(column1,column2,column3) VALUES(%s, %s, %s)", 
[sensor,data,data_type])

Comment: @csharpcoder First variation of the example worked perfectly for me. I struggled to implement the second one.

Answer (score 3):

This is because the number of values does not match the number of arguments.

```
save_data = "INSERT INTO mediciones_historial VALUES('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')" % (sensor, data, data_type, fecha)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Now I have this error: "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1".

Comment: Got it. Your table schema has 5 columns and we missed fecha column in insert query. Have updated my post above.